# How to restrict users from accessing folders outside protected in YII

Tags: yii

I have a "uploads" folder outside my protected folder, where I am saving all the user's profile images, the problem is when someone enters the url like:

`http://localhost/myweb/upload/`
they can see all the images inside that folder.

So, I have two questions:

1. How do I restrict this?
2. Should I create the uploads folder inside the protected folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `.htaccess` file in upload folder and put in the following line in your `.htaccess` file

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what this does actually?
and should I keep the uploads folder inside or outside the protected folder? thanks again.

Comment: It denies direct access to the folder and won't list its contents. I normally use the assets folder so if I were you, I would have created a folder inside the assets folder like /assets/upload/

Answer (score 0):

create .htaccess file and write this "Deny from all" without quote.